# Outputting JSON to dynamic HTML table - how to only output specific columns?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not that familiar with JSON, but ultimately I want to output JSON data in an HTML table, but only specific columns. The JSON itself will always be different, but the headers and their names will always be the same.

I have got the following working, in order to output everything via JavaScript.

```
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Test Output" />
    <p id="showData"></p>
</body>

<script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myData = [JSON DATA GOES HERE]

        // values for headers

        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myData[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // the table
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // create headers

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        } 

        // add rows
        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myData[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // Output
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
</script>
```

Here's some random JSON Data:

```
[{"type":"paragraph","subtype":"p","label":"Paragraph"},{"type":"paragraph","subtype":"p","label":"Paragraph"},{"type":"number","required":false,"label":"Telephone Number","className":"form-control","name":"number-1584622107039","step":5,"userData":["test"]},{"type":"textarea","required":false,"label":"Details of Project","className":"form-control","name":"textarea-1584622084505","subtype":"textarea","rows":8,"userData":["Detail's of the project go here. Hahaha"]},{"type":"text","required":false,"label":"Organisation Name","className":"form-control","name":"text-1584622090644","subtype":"text","userData":["my organisation"]}]
```

How could I print out only the column for "label" and "userData", disregarding everything else?

The above outputs:

[image]

So essentially I just want to output:

[image]

Comment: dont get your point please update your answer with the expected output

Comment: I simply mean, how can I only display specific columns, rather than all the columns. Have updated with image

Comment: use a Map or just an Object with key/value pairs, add if statements.  or array

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, I understand that the `col` variable holds the data that will be displayed to the page. So you can do one thing, instead of putting all the data to the `col` variable you could only store the information of `label` and `userData` field.